# Formatting Expect Script Inside of User Command in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, expect

So I have three installers for NVIDIA's CUDA API -- the first is a driver and comes with nice silent install flag options (but you have to be root and have to have run level 3).

The second two follow are shown manually installing below (cut out the long mess of install afterwards for brevity)

> [root]# sh cudatoolkit_4.1.28_linux_64_rhel5.x.run Verifying archive
>   integrity... All good. Uncompressing NVIDIA
>   CUDA.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
>   Enter install path (default /usr/local/cuda, '/cuda' will be
>   appended):
>  A previous version of CUDA was found in /usr/local/cuda/bin
>   Would you like to uninstall? (yes/no/abort): yes

In other words, I need to recognize:
"Enter install path" and output a '\n'

Now the tricky part is the uninstall may not be always be there.  If it's not I need to simply wait for the install to finish, but if I see "Would you like to uninstall?" I need to output "yes" to complete.

The third and final installer's output is shown below....

> [root]# sh gpucomputingsdk_4.1.28_linux.run
>  Verifying archive
>   integrity... All good.
>  Uncompressing NVIDIA GPU Computing
>   
> SDK............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
>   
>  Enter install path (default ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK):
>   /usr/local/CUDA_SDK
>  
>  Located CUDA at /usr/local/cuda
>  If
>   this is correct, choose the default below.
>  If it is not correct,
>   enter the correct path to CUDA
>  
>  Enter CUDA install path
>   (default /usr/local/cuda):

For this one, there is no uninstall action so it's seemingly a bit simpler.

I just need to detect "Enter install path" and output "/usr/local/CUDA_SDK\n" and then detect "Enter CUDA install path" and output "\n"

My idea was to use a pair of expect scripts -- one for each installer -- but due to the nesting within the double quotes of the command to switch to root, I'm having some difficulties with this.  What I currently have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
CR="\"\n\""
YES="\"Yes\""
INSTALL_PATH_REQUEST="\"Enter install path\""
CUDA_PATH_REQUEST="\"Enter CUDA install path\""
UNINSTALL_REQUEST="\"Would you like to uninstall?\""
TOOLKIT=`ls -t cudatoolkit* | head -n 1`
TOOLKIT_EXPECT="sh $TOOLKIT"
SDK=`ls -t gpucomputingsdk* | head -n 1`
SDK_INSTALL_PATH="\"/usr/local/CUDA_SDK\n\""
SDK_EXPECT="sh $SDK"
/bin/su root -c "yum -q -y install expect expectk;
/sbin/init 3; sh `ls -t NVIDIA*|head -n 1` -s --update -a -X;
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF;
spawn $TOOLKIT_EXPECT
expect $INSTALL_PATH_REQUEST
send $CR
expect $UNINSTALL_REQUEST
send $YES
EOF
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF;
spawn $SDK_EXPECT
expect $INSTALL_PATH_REQUEST
send $SDK_INSTALL_PATH
expect $CUDA_PATH_REQUEST
send $CR
EOF
/sbin/init 5"
```

This switches to root properly (once the password is entered) and installs the driver with the built in options correctly.  It then appears to spawn the second install process and enter the first argument (a carriage return), but seems to exit the second installer prematurely (e.g. I don't see the "yes" option.).

I feel like I'm pretty close, hopefully somebody can point me to where I'm going wrong and suggest the correct syntax.

**NOTES:**
I added the yum install command, as some of the machines I'm installing on didn't have expect (stock `CentOS 6`), so that saves me the trouble there....

Comment: Please don't multi-post -- http://superuser.com/q/412259/4714

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be an issue with timeout here... not sure how long the installer takes.
The default expect timeout is 10 seconds, if it doesn't see the expected text in that time, it will proceed regardless, you could change the timeout values like so:

```
expect -timeout 100 $INSTALL_PATH_REQUEST
```

Also change your $YES from

```
YES="\"Yes\""
```

To:

```
YES="\"Yes\r\""
```

(Best to use \r instead of \n in $CR too)

It's also a good idea to expect some 'safety string' at the end of the install, for example:

```
 expect -timeout 320 "Install Complete."
```

So the expect script doesn't terminate before the spawned process is complete.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out and get back to you how it went!

Comment: Tried this, combined with @glenn jackman solution here:
http://superuser.com/questions/412259/expect-script-inside-bash-script-optional-statement

What ends up happening is I get an error
`invalid command name "/usr/bin/expect" while executing..."`

As you surmised, the timeouts and `'\r'`s helped, but I'm still struggling with the conditional part.  Do I need another EOF after the closing brace following the first (and only) EOF in glenn jackman's solution?

Comment: WOOO!  Once I added that EOF back in everything worked like a charm.  Your timeout proofing combined with glenn jackman's fix to the conditional expect logic made the script work perfectly.... unintendended CUDA install is working perfectly. :)  Yay teamwork!

Here's Jackman's post:
http://superuser.com/questions/412259/expect-script-inside-bash-script-optional-statement