# Query For Latest Version of CUDA SDK/Toolkit From Terminal?

Tags: bash, cuda, installation, expect

Is there a way to -- from the terminal -- query for the latest toolkit/SDK version???

e.g. Does NVIDIA have some sort of server that one can log in and issue a discrete command to get the latest SDK and toolkit??

...................................................................................
**Background:**

I wrote a small script to perform an unattended install of the core CUDA components -- dev drivers, toolkit, and SDK.

Note the drivers already have an automated updated, in that I pass them a flag that tells them to check for the latest version, so I only need to download once and all future updates to the CUDA install will now work

Had some initial errors, but worked it out with a bit of help. [[1]](https://superuser.com/questions/412259/expect-script-inside-bash-script-optional-statement)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150939/formatting-expect-script-inside-of-user-command-in-bash-script).

The `init` is to take down the `X11` server if one is running, in order to complete the video dev driver install.  The `yum` is to install `expect` if it's not present.

```
#!/bin/bash 
CR="\r"
YES="\"Yes\r\""
INSTALL_PATH_REQUEST="\"Enter install path\""
CUDA_PATH_REQUEST="\"Enter CUDA install path\""
UNINSTALL_REQUEST="\"Would you like to uninstall?\""
TOOLKIT=`ls -t cudatoolkit* | head -n 1`
TOOLKIT_EXPECT="sh $TOOLKIT"
SDK=`ls -t gpucomputingsdk* | head -n 1`
SDK_INSTALL_PATH="\"/usr/local/CUDA_SDK\r\""
SDK_EXPECT="sh $SDK"
DUMMY="dummy"
/bin/su root -c "yum -q -y install expect expectk;
/sbin/init 3; sh `ls -t NVIDIA*|head -n 1` -s --update -a -X;
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF;
spawn $TOOLKIT_EXPECT
expect -timeout 300 $INSTALL_PATH_REQUEST
send $CR
expect -timeout 300 {
 {Would you like to uninstall?} {
  send $YES

  exp_continue
 }
 expect -timeout 500 $DUMMY
 eof
}
EOF
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF;
spawn $SDK_EXPECT
expect -timeout 300 $INSTALL_PATH_REQUEST
send $SDK_INSTALL_PATH
expect -timeout 300 $CUDA_PATH_REQUEST
send $CR
expect -timeout 500 $DUMMY
EOF
/sbin/init 5"
```

If someone can figure out how to query the SDK and toolkit remotely for updates, this would be the (almost) perfect unattended installer.  Any other advice would also be appreciated if you think I'm missing anything.

P.S. You need the dev driver, toolkit, and SDK files in the same directory for this to work.  When it asks you for the password, that's asking for your root password.  I choose to install the SDK in `/usr/local/CUDA_SDK/` to allow all users access.  If you wish to install it in another location, change it in the script.

Comment: This is implicitly for Linux distributions which use yum for package management and don't have X11 running in run state 3, I presume?

Comment: Yes on the latter, not sure on the former -- does CUDA SDK work with YUM?  If so I was unaware and I would switch to that surely... But if that's the case, yes it would be useful for the former case as well.

Comment: Your script runs yum itself...

Comment: The cluster I run on, is mostly a CPU cluster, our CUDA machines are also workstations, so typically they're in run level 5, being used by my co-workers, hence the switching the run state.  And yes, I have given them a nasty surprise once or twice, though I try to run my upgrades in the evenings/weekends. :)

Comment: OHHH, right, I get your question now... the `yum` is in case `expect` isn't installed... you can swap that out for whatever your distro's update processs is.  The key thing is the unattended install needs `expect` to handle the questions from the toolkit and SDK's installers.... but yea, looking for a way to remotely query them for the latest version (like I'm able to do with the dev-drivers via the `--update` flag...

Comment: I run on `Centos`, if that's helpful for others... but yea, be sure to swap the `yum` for whatever you're using for package management...

Comment: @talonmies sorry for the cluelessness, been trying to get this working for a couple weeks, just now finally did, forgot altogether that the `yum` was in there so didn't follow you immediately. :P  Added that because I found some of the machines didn't have expect on it, but I suppose that is a downside given that it makes it less distro portable....

Comment: @talonmies Did you vote to close?  I asked a specific question -- how to perform an automated update/query of latest toolkit/SDK version from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe NVIDIA provides a way to query the latest released version of driver, toolkit, SDK, etc.  On the windows driver there is now an auto-update feature, and the linux driver may have one too (not sure), but I don't think we have a way to query the current release version.

There are always various driver versions out for different platforms and technologies (like prerelease developer drivers for Tesla, WHQL drivers for windows, etc).

I think most cluster operators would only want to upgrade to stable releases of any software, and that only happens a few times per year at most, so I think it is not a big deal to have a human check (and download) latest versions, then automate the installation from the downloaded files.

Comment: True, but NVIDIA does provided an automated update in their drivers.  It appears to grab the latest stable version, as you surmise.  I was hopeful that their might be some undiscussed similiar option for the SDK/toolkit, but if there's not that's an answer too, I suppose. :)

Comment: Definitely not for the SDK or toolkit, currently.